# Why are these functions differently evaluated

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I was experimenting with haskell, and while trying to improve the readability of my code I suddenly changed the behaviour of it. I would have thought these two variants would be equivalent.

Original:

```
f :: Eq c => c -> c -> [[c]] -> [[c]]
f d c acc  
  | c == d    = [] : acc
  | otherwise = ([c] ++ (head acc)) : tail acc

split :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
split delim = foldr (f delim) [[]]
```

Here is the second one:

```
f' :: Eq c => c -> c -> [[c]] -> [[c]]
f' d c (currentWord:wordsSoFar)  
  | c == d    = [] : currentWord : wordsSoFar
  | otherwise = (c : currentWord) : wordsSoFar

split' :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
split' delim = foldr (f' delim) [[]]
```

Here are the results of running the two:

```
*Main> take 1 (split 5 [1..])
[[1,2,3,4]]
*Main> take 1 (split' 5 [1..])
*** Exception: stack overflow
```

Comment: in your second code try changing `split'` to `split`

Comment: @maioman That doesn't answer anything.

Comment: `foldr` is a kind of "magic" thing that generates very deep recursion, but then gets optimized (or not) by compiler. I would suggest trying to rewrite your code in terms of `foldl'`, which works at linear recursion depth.

The big difference in two examples is that first `f` doesn't examine it's `acc` upon application.

Comment: @KonstantineRybnikov How do you expect `foldl'` to work on an infinite list?

Comment: @sepp2k good catch, thanks :) Every time I get into this topic I forget about many details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first version only needs to evaluate `acc` when you call `head` and `tail` on it, so no evaluation takes place when `c == d`.

The second version needs to know whether acc is empty or not before it does anything else as none of the other code must execute if the pattern does not match. This means that `acc` has to be evaluated even if `c == d`. This leads to an infinite loop.

You can make the second version work by using an irrefutable pattern like this:

```
f' d c ~(currentWord:wordsSoFar) =
```

By making the pattern irrefutable, you're saying that you know that the pattern will match, so no check is necessary. If `acc` were empty, this would cause an error to happen when (and if) you used `currentWord` and `wordsSoFar` instead of a non-exhaustive pattern error happening right away (and regardless of whether `currentWord` and `wordsSoFar` are actually used).

Comment: this is incorrect in one respect: even when `c /= d`, `acc` is still not forced if only head of head of `f`'s result is requested.

Comment: @sepp2k Why does `acc` has to be fully evaluated in the second case ? Why not just evaluate it to WHNF ?

Comment: I assumed you meant `head` and `tail` instead of `hd` and `tl`, so I edited the answer accordingly. Feel free to change it back if this was a mistake.

Comment: @Sibi It only has to be evaluated to WHNF, but that's already enough to cause the infinite loop because `acc = foldr (f' delim) [[]] restOfTheList` and that in turn needs to evaluate its own acc to WHNF first thing, which is `foldr (f' delim) [[]] restOfTheRestOfTheList` and so on ad infinitum.

Comment: Ok, let me see if I get it. The value of acc will be a recursive call to foldr itself. And, therefore we must evaluate it before we know if it will be an empty list that would not match the pattern?

Answer (score 2):

I think *this* should be equivalent:

```
f d c acc | c == d = [] : acc
f d c (currentWord:wordsSoFar) = (c : currentWord) : wordsSoFar
```

Notice that if `c == d` then we don't attempt to determine whether `acc` is empty or not. (All versions of your code will actually fail if `c == d` and `acc == []`; I presume this never happens.)

Comment: I think that `acc@(currentWord:wordsSoFar)` should work as well